# How to raise exceptions as json?

Tags: python, exception, falconframework

At the service level of my application, I am raising an exception and I want it to be printed as JSON to the browser.

I implemented it as stated in the documentation:

```
raise falcon.HTTPError(
    '12345 - My Custom Error',
    'some text'
).to_json()
```

And the output from the console:

```
TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException
```

Anybody had this issue before and could help me with this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to raise a string. The correct way to do that is with [set_error_serializer()](http://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/api.html#falcon.API.set_error_serializer).

The example from the documentation seems like exactly what you need (plus YAML support).

```
def my_serializer(req, resp, exception):
    representation = None

    preferred = req.client_prefers(('application/x-yaml',
                                    'application/json'))

    if preferred is not None:
        if preferred == 'application/json':
            representation = exception.to_json()
        else:
            representation = yaml.dump(exception.to_dict(),
                                       encoding=None)
        resp.body = representation
        resp.content_type = preferred

    resp.append_header('Vary', 'Accept')

app = falcon.API()
app.set_error_serializer(my_serializer)
```

Comment: hey thanks for your answer, great:) one more question, why do i need yaml when every browser supports json and json it the preferred format?

cant i just do "resp.body = exception.to_json()" ?

Comment: You don't need it for browsers. Usually you at it for power users with python, php, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Create custom exception class explained in falcon docs, search for add_error_handler

```
class RaiseUnauthorizedException(Exception):
    def handle(ex, req, resp, params):
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_401
        response = json.loads(json.dumps(ast.literal_eval(str(ex))))
        resp.body = json.dumps(response)
```

Add custom exception class to falcon API object

```
api = falcon.API()
api.add_error_handler(RaiseUnauthorizedException)
```

import Custom exception class and pass your message

```
message = {"status": "error", "message" : "Not authorized"}
RaiseUnauthorizedException(message)
```